# How to Disable Image like Iphone in ANDROID?

Tags: android, android-imageview

i want to disable view of image in my app.(like iphone). when my activity is launch i show one Image in Imageview then if i click on image i want to make it disable it. disable in the sense it will become more transparent.

Thanks....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

onClicking the `ImageView`

```
myImageView.getDrawable().mutate().setAlpha(70);
myImageView.invalidate();
```

this will make the image somewhat transparent. Lesser the value in `setAlpha()`, the more transparent the image will become.

Comment: Minor nit pick, mutate is a method not a field.